# Can I have a class within a class in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class NoteLink
{

    public IList<NoteLinkDetail> NoteLinkDetails
    {
        get { return _noteLinkDetails; }
    }
    private List<NoteLinkDetail> _noteLinkDetails = new List<NoteLinkDetail>();

    public NoteLink()
    {
        _noteLinkDetails = new List<NoteLinkDetail>();
    }

}
```

and then another class that's used just within the first class.

```
public class NoteLinkDetail
{
    public string L { get; set; }
    public string R { get; set; }
}
```

Is there anything I could do to optimize this. I DO need the second class as I use JSON to store the contents of NoteLinkDetail in a string. However is there such a thing as an inner class in C#?  Any recommendation on how I could optimize this code? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there are inner classes in C#. [See this answer on SO for more details.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804453/using-inner-classes-in-c)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just nest it.

```
public class NoteLink
{
    // ...

    public NoteLink()
    {
        _noteLinkDetails = new List<NoteLinkDetail>();
    }

    public class NoteLinkDetail
    {
        public string L { get; set; }
        public string R { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Moreover, if it is not exposed outside the outer class, your inner class can even be `private` and **stay invisible** to outer class users.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, C# allows nested classes.

C# nested classes are much more like nested classes in C++ than "inner classes" in Java.  This link explains:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/01/685248.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Sure; just declare the inner class from within the outer class

```
class NoteLink
{
    class NoteLinkDetail
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: But then how do I call that class externally because I need to do some JSON work on the inner class to serialize it?

Comment: NoteLink.NoteLinkDetail detail = new NoteLink.NoteLinkDetail

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have nested classes in C#