# c# - Nested classes? Properties with properties?

Tags: c#, class, nested

I would like to create a class with properties that have subproperties...

In other words, if I did something like:

```
Fruit apple = new Fruit();
```

I would want something like:

```
apple.eat(); //eats apple
MessageBox.Show(apple.color); //message box showing "red"
MessageBox.Show(apple.physicalProperties.height.ToString()); // message box saying 3
```

I would think it would be done like:

```
class Fruit{
    public void eat(){
        MessageBox.Show("Fruit eaten");
    }
    public string color = "red";
    public class physicalProperties{
        public int height = 3;
    }

}
```

...but, if that were working, I wouldn't be on here...

Comment: so what's the problem then batman?

Comment: ..but, if that were working, I wouldn't be on here...

Comment: `apple` doesn't have `physicalProperties` now, only `Fruit` does. It's just a type now. And you definitely can't access its `height`, because `physicalProperties` doesn't have a `height`, only its instances do.

Comment: LOL! Did anyone else notice the personification of the apple in this example? i.e. "since when can apples eat stuff?" :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So close!  Here's how your code should read:

```
class Fruit{
    public void eat(){
        MessageBox.Show("Fruit eaten");
    }
    public string color = "red";
    public class PhysicalProperties{
        public int height = 3;
    }
    // Add a field to hold the physicalProperties:
    public PhysicalProperties physicalProperties = new PhysicalProperties();
}
```

A class just defines the signature, but nested classes don't automatically become properties.

As a side note, there's also a couple things I'd recommend, to follow .NET's "best practices":

- Don't nest classes unless necessary
- All Public members should be Properties instead of Fields
- All Public members should be PascalCase, not camelCase.

I'm sure there's plenty of documentation on best practices too, if you're so inclined.

Comment: Don't you need to create a instance else height won't be accessible

Comment: If I'm not supposed to nest classes, how do I add properties to the properties?

Comment: @Walkemeo Nested classes is just referring to the namespace ... I shouldn't have even brought it up, it's more of a preference.  Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804453/using-inner-classes-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Walkerneo - You can define the class outside the "Fruit" class, but still create an instance of it within the Fruit class. Much as String is defined elsewhere, but you still have a String instance in the Fruit class.

Comment: Also, what if I want that property to return a value if none of its members are called?

Comment: @Walkerneo I'm not sure I correctly understand your question.  If none of its members are called, then `apple.physicalProperties` returns a `PhysicalProperties` instance, the same way `apple.color` returns a `String` instance.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Fruit{
    public void eat(){
        MessageBox.Show("Fruit eaten");
    }
    public string color = "red";
    //you have declared the class but you havent used this class
    public class physicalProperties{
        public int height = 3;

    }
    //create a property here of type PhysicalProperties
    public physicalProperties physical;
}
```

Comment: This should give a Null Reference exception for height

Comment: @V4Vendetta, it sure does! Now what?

Comment: Check my answer, instantiate in the constructor of Fruit

Comment: The field needs to be initialized or you'll get `null-reference` exceptions.  `public physicalProperties physical = new physicalProperties();`

Answer (score 0):

Can you extrapolate the class, then reference it?

```
class Fruit{
    public void eat(){
        MessageBox.Show("Fruit eaten");
    }
    public string color = "red";
    public physicalProperties{
        height = 3;
    }

}

public class physicalProperties{
        public int height = 3;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Fruit{
    public class physicalProperties{
        public int height = 3;
    }
}
```

`Fruit.physicalProperties` does indeed declare another type, but:

1. It will  be private, only available to the members of `Fruit` unless you declare it `public`.
2. Creating a type does not create an instance of that type, or member of `Fruit` to allow users of `Fruit` to access it.

You need to add:

```
class Fruit {
  private physicalProperties props;
  public physicalProperties PhysicalProperties { get; private set; }
```

and in the (default) constructor of `Fruit` assign `PhysicalProperties` an instance of `physicalProperties`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to expose the property as it is contained for the instance of the class `physicalProperties` so maybe you could do like

```
public Fruit()
{
    physical = new physicalProperties();
}
```

And a property which gives it back

```
public int Height { get { return physical.height;}}
```

OR

```
public physicalProperties physical;
```

so that you can do `apple.physical.height`

Answer (score 0):

```
class Fruit{
    public void eat(){
        MessageBox.Show("Fruit eaten");
    }
    public string color = "red";
    public class physicalProperties{
        public int height = 3;
    }
    // create a new instance of the class so its public members
    // can be accessed
    public physicalProperties PhysicalProperties = new physicalProperties();
}
```

You can then access the sub-properties like so:

```
Fruit apple = new Fruit();
MessageBox.Show(apple.PhysicalProperties.height.ToString());
```